# The type or namespace name 'SqlServer' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to configure my .NET Core Entity Framework app to use SQL Server, but I can't seem to access the namespace.

Startup.cs (origin of the error)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
```

Project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0"
}
```

I have run `dotnet restore` successfully.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be lovely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is no namespace "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer". Everything related to SQL Server is in the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" namespace. See for yourself: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I got the `.SqlServer` .part from some blog or tutorial I believe.